# Xamarin forms - iOS: Images not visible on real device but visible on emulator

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I made app from Visual studio Xamarin.Forms Shell template. I added local images to android(drawable folders) and iOS project (assets catalog). In Android is everything OK. But in iOS project is image visible only in iPhone simulator. Image does not show on real device (iPhone). And I don´t know where is problem. I am using Xamarin.Form 4.8

[Images in assets catalog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZA08.png)

Item detail page with included image.

```
 <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
    <Image Source="baseline_home_black_48.png" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"></Image>
    <Image Source="baseline_home_black_48"  HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"></Image>
    ...
</StackLayout>
```

[Link to download project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12fqU3DioLDvqJk_oe5d7jisMNHxgJhAx/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try to remove and re-add the image with a different name. Also clean and re-build your project.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I tried it. I used new name house.png but nothing happened.

Comment: That's weird. I test your project and the image shows on my real device.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT: Thank for testing. Maybe is something wrong with my dev iPhone...or visual studio deploy settings.

Comment: You can try another iPhone or another image to see if it works.

Comment: I tried pack app to ipa package and distribute it via MS App center. And images are OK. So there is maybe problem with  deploy setting in visual studio. But now...I cant see iPhone in visual studio :(

Comment: Are you using the latest Visual-Studio? Please update it if not.

Comment: I have last version of Visual studio. I tried clean bin and obj folders too. I cant see images 
 when I use VS debug on real device. I can see images only on emulator or use archive and deploy IPA via MS App Center.

Comment: Did you delete the app in the iPhone before you install it again? Please remove the image totally(clean/rebuild after remove) and then re-add again. Or you can try another image to make sure if this problem is caused by the image or other things.

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue.

When running our app on real iOS devices (in debug) the images do not show. Images show OK when using an iOS simulator or Android. This has been tested with both local and remote hosted images and neither work on a real iOS device.

We've been developing this app for over 4yrs so it's not something we've missed. It's just stopped working. The versions of iOS, Xcode and VS and XF do not seem to make a difference so it's pretty strange.

We also use ffimageloader and see the same issue with and without cached images.

Comment: Are you sure that the visual studio caused the problem?

Answer (score 1):

We had this issue and spent (wasted?) a  few hours looking in to this.

Images were not appearing on real iOS devices (in debug) but were working fine for simulators.  Local and remote images resulted in the same issue.

The issue appears to be a project setting.

Removal of --interpreter from the 'Additional *mtouch* arguments:' field seems to get it working.  We believe the checkbox 'Enable the Mono interpreter' means the same thing and when checked images should still work and hot-reload too.

[image: iOS Project settings for DEBUG]

Comment: My iosBuild settings [https://ibb.co/T4Kdq6N](https://ibb.co/T4Kdq6N). And images are not visible. Appicon too. Everything is ok when I use testFlight (icon and images). Its very interesting, that on real device is xamarin app icon. Because I removed it from project.

Answer (score 0):

HI In my case I was using two different systems to build the application. The image names contains - instead of _ once I correct it and include in the project it worked for me.

Have a great day.